# Override Button, make backcolor fill from left to right like progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to creat custom Button.
whether button has added in control, it override Paint Event, and make back color moving and Fill from left to right, which look like progress Bar.

This is my logic. But, I think this is not a proper way. please suggest proper way to get animation BackColor.
This code base on button Size :

```
private void customButton()
{
     Button customButton=new Button();
      customButton.Size.width=1;
      custonButton.BackColor=Color.Green;
     this.Controls.Add(customButton);
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i+= 5)
    {

         customButton.Size.width += 1;
    }
}
```

But, this code creat a button have width=50px;, and the width will expand from left to right, look like progress Bar
I want to creat and override default OnPaint event, creat a button have 50pixel and backColor will moving(animation) from left to right when it 's added by parent controls.
i am new to C# and not know much about OnPaint event.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cksxshce(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: A label is a better control to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty example on how you can change the background contents of a button.

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(button1.Width, button1.Height);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
using (var lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Black, Color.LimeGreen, 0f))
    g.FillRectangle(lgb, rect);

button1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

The button itself can be modified to not have a 3D style if you want to, resizing it still works just fine. The point here is to paint it rather than resize it.

Comment: @LinhBi You mean like this: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,cb5c00483936b8f7 ?